# Adding Regression Lines to Multiple Scatter Plots

Tags: r, regression

Had a look around and couldn't find an answer to my question, so finally stopped lurking. I've been creating multiple scatter plots comparing each column to the others as shown here

[image]

I used the script

```
attach(`File`)
plot(`Files`[,c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8)])
```

However I can't seem to correctly input the command to annotate the regression line and r2 value onto the graphs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Comment: Use the *.panel options in the `pairs` function.  A simple example of their use appears in the code I posted at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/65948.

Comment: Thanks I will try this as well as the comment by Hamed

Answer (score 4):

here is the solution. Assume Z is your design matrix.

```
z=matrix(rnorm(500),ncol=5)

pairs( z, panel=function(x,y){
  points(x,y)
  abline(lm(y~x), col='red')
  text(0,1.5,labels = paste('R2=',round((cor(x,y))^2,2)) ,col='red' )
})
```

and result should be like this
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, I will try this!